# How do I update local value of PHP MEMORY_LIMIT in Bitnami (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, memory, bitnami

I am running Wordpress instance in Amazon Lightsail using Bitnami. The theme I want to install requires me to set **MEMORY_LIMIT = 128M**. I was able to update **Master Value**, but the **Local Value remains unchanged**.

Is there a way I can update the memory_limit of local value in Bitnami? or local value belongs to each WordPress theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 things you need to do.

Just update the PHP memory limit by updating `installdir/php/etc/php.ini` file and setting to `memory_limit = 128M`. 
This will change PHP memory limit and is applicable to entire server.

Now update the local limit 
`installdir/apps/akeneo/htdocs/app/console` and update `ini_set('memory_limit','128M');`

Here you can have different websites installed on same server, and `app` is one such application.

You can find more information at

> https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/akeneo/administration/increase-memory-limit/

Comment: Also restart the server :-)